# Yo generator tries to make a brand new MEAN app when I try to use a subgenerator

Tags: meanjs, yo

So when I run

```
yo meanjs:crud-module foo
```

I get this

```
You're using the official MEAN.JS generator.
? What mean.js version would you like to generate? (Use arrow keys)
  master 
❯ 0.4.0 
  0.4.1
```

and it tries to take me through the process of cloning the sample meanJS app.

Why is it not behaving as a sub-generator?

**Edit**

I was using MEANJS 4.0, which the current YO generators do not support. I installed the in-development yo generators with

sudo npm install -g meanjs/generator-meanjs#0.4-dev

and now I can use the vertical-module subgenerator.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the project using the generator? Your project probably doesn't have a `.yo-rc.json` file so the generator doesn't know there is a yo project.

Comment: I did make this project with the yo generator. Yo just clones the MEAN repo and does not seem to give me a .yorc.json file.

Answer (score 0):

The 0.4.x generator is in progress.
[Github repo](https://github.com/meanjs/generator-meanjs)